# SQL Server xml deserialization

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, deserialization

I have this example of script for deserialization of an xml, but I'm getting a weird description from it (attached)[image]

How can I write this to get `Atom cloth - Black/grey` - which is the *right* deserialization?

Thank you

```
declare @x xml
set @x = '<options>
<option>
<code>99248</code>
<description>Atom&amp;#32;cloth&amp;#32;&amp;#45;&amp;#32;Black&amp;#47;grey</description>
<monthlycost>0.00</monthlycost>
<allowed />
</option>
<option>
<code>99239</code>
<description>Metallic&amp;#32;&amp;#45;&amp;#32;Sargasso&amp;#32;blue</description>
<monthlycost>12.85</monthlycost>
<allowed />
</option>
</options>'


select 
    pref.value('(code/text())[1]', 'varchar(32)') as Code           
   ,pref.value('(description/text())[1]', 'varchar(80)') as [Description]
   ,pref.value('(monthlycost/text())[1]', 'varchar(32)') as MontlyCost  
from 
   @X.nodes('/options/option') AS Options(pref)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `value()` method twice to unescape the entities twice, for example :

```
select 
    pref.value('(code/text())[1]', 'varchar(32)') as Code           
   ,pref.value('(description/text())[1]', 'varchar(80)') as [Description]
   ,CONVERT(XML, 
            pref.value('(description/text())[1]', 'varchar(80)')
    ).value('.', 'varchar(80)') as [DescriptionFixed]
   ,pref.value('(monthlycost/text())[1]', 'varchar(32)') as MontlyCost  
from 
   @X.nodes('/options/option') AS Options(pref)
```

**<kbd>[`Sqlfiddle Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db/45)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
|  Code |                                 Description |         DescriptionFixed | MontlyCost |
|-------|---------------------------------------------|--------------------------|------------|
| 99248 | Atom&#32;cloth&#32;&#45;&#32;Black&#47;grey |  Atom cloth - Black/grey |       0.00 |
| 99239 |    Metallic&#32;&#45;&#32;Sargasso&#32;blue | Metallic - Sargasso blue |      12.85 |
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful.

Comment: I have another one now ... did I mention I hate xml? :D

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your descriptions have been HTML escaped and then XML escaped.

Original:

```
Atom cloth - Black/grey
```

HTML Escape and convert spaces, slash, and dash to HTML number codes:

```
Atom&#32;cloth&#32;&#45;&#32;Black&#47;grey
```

XML Escape and convert ampersand to `&amp;`:

```
Atom&amp;#32;cloth&amp;#32;&amp;#45;&amp;#32;Black&amp;#47;grey
```

And that's what you have in your variable:

```
Atom&amp;#32;cloth&amp;#32;&amp;#45;&amp;#32;Black&amp;#47;grey
```

You'll have to push the descriptions back through unescape functions, but I don't believe there are any native functions that do that.  There's the value method like this like you're doing:

```
declare @x xml = '';

select @x.value('"Atom&amp;#32;cloth&amp;#32;&amp;#45;&amp;#32;Black&amp;#47;grey"','nvarchar(50)');
```

But that just unescapes the XML and gets you the HTML escaped result:

```
Atom&#32;cloth&#32;&#45;&#32;Black&#47;grey
```

You have to do it again to get your final result:

```
select @x.value('"Atom&#32;cloth&#32;&#45;&#32;Black&#47;grey"','nvarchar(50)')

Atom cloth - Black/grey
```